# Cosa vuol dire "dare passata a qualcosa"? Si tratta di un'espressione arcaica?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Uranio* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ringraziai, feci doverosamente il mio numero, illustrai un certo nuovo prodotto, presi nota di una ordinazione abbastanza cospicua, salutai e **diedi passata alla faccenda**. Ma il giorno dopo, sulla mia scrivania da 1,2 metri quadrati, trovai deposto un pacchetto, alla mia cortese attenzione.

Questo accade dopo una lunga conversazione di Levi con un cliente, che spiega che, durante la guerra, aveva ricevuto uranio in cambio delle informazioni date a un gruppo di tedeschi che fuggivano in Svizzera.

Il mio dubbio è sul significato dell'espressione "dare passata a una faccenda". Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/passata) ho trovato la locuzione "dare una passata", ma non sono per niente sicura che sia lo stesso:

> **2. a.** Il passare rapidamente, il far scorrere qualcosa su una superficie, o il far passare attraverso qualcosa, una volta, o brevemente e velocemente; spec. nella locuz. *dare una p.*: *dare una p. di vernice, una p. col pennello, alla porta*; *dare una p. con lo straccio al pavimento*; *dare una p. al vestito col ferro da stiro*; *dare una p. al brodo*, filtrarlo; *dare una p. ai capelli*, ravviarli alla svelta col pettine. Anche, rapida scorsa, lettura veloce: *dare una p. al giornale, alla lezione*; o breve rosolatura: *dare una p. in padella alla carne, alla verdura*.

Quindi, potrebbe significare scorrere velocemente, ma che cosa? Forse fare un rapido riassunto mentale della conversazione avuta con questo cliente?

Ho trovato l'espressione anche sull'articolo ["Una nuova frontiera. La penetrazione commerciale genovese in Marocco durante il sultanato di Mohammed III (1757-1790)"](https://www.academia.edu/24796958/Una_nuova_frontiera_La_penetrazione_commerciale_genovese_in_Marocco_durante_il_sultanato_di_Mohammed_III_1757_1790_in_M_Barbano_A_Castagnino_E_Locci_a_cura_di_Attraverso_la_Storia_Percorsi_mediterranei_2016_pp_88_107), di Andrea Zappia, in una citazione di una lettera Settecentesca (grassetto mio):

> «una tale notizia mi ha fatto allora determinare a scrivere in dirittura io stesso a S.M.I. una mia lettera in Arabo, dove la ringraziavo a nome della Repubblica intanto dell’accordato favore, e la pregavo degnarsi di dare li ordini opportuni per l’accompimento nella nave veneta la Stella del Mare venuta a bella posta per levare un carico, e accompagnando la stessa lettera si altre mie alli amici miei alla Corte, insistevo presso del mio fratello e presso di tutti che fosse assistito questo carricamento da farsi; La mia lettera non ebbe effetto ne risposta, perché dissimulando S.M. **diede passata alla lettera** non solo, ma a tutto quello ancora che gli fu esposto da tutti li amici; Siccome mi stava a cuore un tale affare, per non protrarlo maggiormente, e per insistere con effcaccia riscrissi altra lettera al
> Re dello stesso tenore sullo stesso proposito, ma [...].»

Infatti, ricercando su Google "diede passata" o "diedi passata", se ne trovano alcune occorrenze, ma sembrano tutte (o quasi) di testi antichi,  per esempio, un testo di [Giuliano de' Ricci](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/giuliano-de-ricci_(Dizionario-Biografico)/) sulle opere di Macchiavelli che si riproduce su parecchi libri (grassetto mio):

> Prima da Paolo IV e poi dal Concilio di Trento li anni 1557 e 1564 furono proibite e dannate tutte le sue opere; e perchè levatone alcune poche cose, elle restano tali che si possono ammettere, fu dato cura l’anno 1573 a me Giuliano de’ Ricci e a Niccolò Machiavelli mio cugino, ambedue suoi nipoti, io figliuolo di una
> figliuola e messer Niccolò figliuolo di un suo figliuolo, come appare da una lettera scritta alli detti dagl’ Illustriss. Sigg. Cardinali deputati sopra la rivista dell’ Indice, data in Roma alli 3 agosto 1573, sottoscritta da frate
> Antonio Posi, allora Segretario di detti Cardinali; e sebbene si faticò attorno alla
> detta revisione, e si corressero tutte, e a Roma si mandò le correzioni delle
> Storie, sino adesso che siamo nel 1594, non si è condotto questa opera a fine, perchè nello stringere il negozio volevano quelli Signori che si ristampassino
> sotto altro nome, **al che si diede passata**.

Ricercando "dare passata" con la funzione "in sequenza" sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000699.jpg), si trova una citazione dal romanzo [*Vita di Alberto Pisani*](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:Opere_(Dossi)_I.djvu/243) di Carlo Dossi, del 1870 (grassetto mio):

> E, com’egli avea voluto, per **dare passata alla emozione** che gl’imbragiava la gota, arrischiarsi a delle disinvoltuie, ajutando, ad esempio, l’ostina a dispiegar la tovaglia, a porre giù i tondi e i bicchieri, a cavar l'àqua dal pozzo, questa emozione era invece aumentata;

Anche in questa [*Rassegna critica della letteratura italiana*](https://archive.org/details/rassegnacriticad910napouoft/page/n5/mode/2up), un testo pubblicato nel 1904, si [legge](https://archive.org/stream/rassegnacriticad78napouoft/rassegnacriticad78napouoft_djvu.txt) (grassetto mio):

> Beatrice **darebbe passata a marito** pochi mesi prima di morire, e pochi mesi sarebbe durato questo primo traviamento del poeta.

Una volta visti tutti questi esempi, il significato di "dare passata a qualcosa" potrebbe essere "dimenticare qualcosa", "mettere una pietra sopra qualcosa"? Si tratterebbe di un'espressione arcaica?

Infatti, sulla [quarta edizione del *Vocabolario degli accademici della Crusca*](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=PASSATA&rewrite=1) si trova:

> *Definiz*:    §. I. Dar passata. Lat. *rem petenti denegare*. Gr. *ἀνανεύειν*. 
> *Esempio*:  *Varch. Ercol. 87*. Dar cartaccia, metafora presa da' giucatori, è passarsi leggiermente d'alcuna cosa, e non rispondere a chi ti domanda o rispondere meno, che non si conviene a chi t'ha o punto, o dimandato d'alcuna cosa; il che si dice ancor dar passata, o dare una stagnata. 
> *Esempio*:  *Segn. stor*. 1. 4. Rimutatisi di parere ec. non vollero farlo, e dettono, come si dice, passata.

Non mi sembra, però, una definizione molto chiara: "passarsi leggiermente d'alcuna cosa?", rifiutarsi di rispondere a una domanda o di fare qualcosa?

Comment: Il senso sembra essere “diedi come conclusa la faccenda”.

Comment: Istintivamente, non pensarci più.

Comment: Sì, @Evgeniy: dagli esempi che ho trovato, sembra proprio che il significato possa essere questo: dimenticare, mettere una pietra sopra, non pensarci più.